# Calculating 2 object keys/columns from array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

So I was working on the some column merging and filtering,but I am having trouble calculating 2 object keys (columns) from an array of objects and then mapping that result to an object key to a new array

Example:

```
var foodRevenue = [{
    "Month": "2011-01",
    "week1_Revenue": "100.00",
    "week2_Revenue": "300.51",
    "Week3_Reenue": "200.09",
    "Month1_TotalRevenue": "0"
}];
```

I want to calculate the sum of  `week1`, `week2`, and `week3` and the result to map on `Month1_TotalRevenue`. Then creating a new array that would filter Month and Month1_TotalRevenue to that array. Like so:

```
{"Month": "2011-01", "Month1_TotalRevenue": "600.60"}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: There are no arrays shown, only objects... It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: FYI, it's typically safer to perform currency arithmetic times 100 so addition of fractional currency doesn't incur floating point error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may destructure your object properties and sum up desired ones, using `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const  foodRevenue = {
      "Month": "2011-01",
      "week1_Revenue": "100.00",
      "week2_Revenue": "300.51",
      "Week3_Reenue": "200.09",
      "Month1_TotalRevenue": "0"
    },
    {Month, Month1_TotalRevenue, week1_Revenue,...revenue} = foodRevenue,
    result = {
      Month,
      week1_Revenue,
      Month1_TotalRevenue: 
        Object
          .values({...revenue,week1_Revenue})
          .reduce((s,r) => s+=+r, +Month1_TotalRevenue)
          .toFixed(2)
    }
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: if I wanted to include "week1_Revenue" to the new array, would I add it to the  result?

Comment: I added"week1_Revenue to result, but when I did that, it does not include week1 calculations into the foodRevenue calculations for MOnth_Revenue

Comment: @MarkAAvila : you may check out example for `week1_Revenue` standing out

Comment: @MarkAAvila : another thing that should be noted, if `Month1_TotalRevenue` is not 0, weekly revenues will be added to its value, if that is not a desired behavior, simply replace `+Month1_TotalRevenue` inside `reduce()` body with 0

Comment: note that foodRevenue is already an Object since originally it was a string so I JSON.parse()

Comment: @MarkAAvila : yes, I see. I guess, [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is what confused you a bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209470/discussion-between-mark-a-avila-and-yevgen-gorbunkov).

Comment: @MarkAAvila: it's 20:30 in my time zone and I'm away from computer, so if you're having issue with above code, drop me a message over here - I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

@Yevgen-Gorbunkov's answer is more concise...

```js
    var foodRevenue = [{
        "Month": "2011-01",
        "week1_Revenue": "100.00",
        "week2_Revenue": "300.51",
        "Week3_Revenue": "200.09",
        "Month1_TotalRevenue": "0"
    }];


 let yearlyRevenue = foodRevenue.map((foodRevenue) => {
    let costs = 0

    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(foodRevenue)) {
      if(key.indexOf('_Revenue') > -1){ // check if the key has _Revenue suffix
        costs += +value // +value change string to number
      }
    }

    console.log(costs);
    
    const transformed = { 
        Month: foodRevenue.Month,
        Month1_TotalRevenue: costs
    }

    return transformed
});

console.log(yearlyRevenue)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to calculate week1 and week2 only. how would I change the if statement?

Comment: if I know for definite I need only 2 props and I am sure of it then Id just do `const total = +foodRevenue.week1_Revenue + +foodRevenue.week2Revenue`

Comment: so I would replace let const?

Comment: let and const are just keywords. nothing to do with the total. `const transformed = { 
    Month: foodRevenue.Month,
    Month1_TotalRevenue: +foodRevenue.week1_Revenue + +foodRevenue.week2Revenue
}`

Comment: On your if statement, it would calculate all the index that has _revenue. That's the part I am confused.

Comment: `Object.entries(foodRevenue)` will convert the object to an array of key, value. Then because there other keys e.g. Month1_TotalRevenue as I iterate over the array I would need to remove unwanted keys and I only get values from keys that has a suffix `_Revenue` It's a bit of a naive way to capture all keys/values. If there is 4th week it will capture that. if there is only 1 week that will get captured too as long as property has `_Revenue` suffix.

Comment: But if you know for sure that you will always have 2 weeks nothing more nothing less I would just do `+foodRevenue.week1_Revenue + +foodRevenue.week2_Revenue`. Because there is no need consider cases of 1 week 3 weeks or 4 weeks or 100 weeks. And I would not use the `for` loop

Comment: I see what you mean. I get it now. Last question. What if there was another set inside the object.var foodRevenue = [{"Month" : "2011-02-02", ...}, {"Month": "2012-02-03,...}],do I need to add something to add it to an new array of object containing these 2 sub sets

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Map` along with the function `reduce` as follow

This approach uses an array with the keys in the desired output, that way it's more dynamic.

```js
let foodRevenue = [{"Month": "2011-01",    "week1_Revenue": "100.00",    "week2_Revenue": "300.51",    "Week3_Reenue": "200.09",    "Month1_TotalRevenue": "0"}];
let inArray = ["Month", "week1_Revenue"];
let accumulator = "Month1_TotalRevenue";
let result = foodRevenue.map(revenue => {
  let obj = Object.entries(revenue).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (inArray.includes(k)) r = Object.assign(r, {[k]: revenue[k]});
    return Object.assign(r, {[accumulator]: +(r[accumulator] || (r[accumulator] = 0)) + +v})
  }, {});
  
  obj[accumulator] = obj[accumulator].toFixed(2);
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the toFixed(), would that also have the decimal to be in the nearest thousandths?

Comment: if I wanted to include the week1_Revenue to the array without messing up the calculation, would that be possible?

Comment: @MarkAAvila see the updated answer

Comment: How could I change the order. Swapping Month1 and week1 order?