# Swapping order of calculated object keys javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Refer here: [Calculating 2 object keys/columns from array of objects Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639632/calculating-2-object-keys-columns-from-array-of-objects-javascript)

Example:

```
var foodRevenue = {
      "Month": "2011-01",
      "week1_Revenue": "100.00",
      "week2_Revenue": "300.51",
      "Week3_Reenue": "200.09",
      "Month1_TotalRevenue": "0"
    },
    {Month, Month1_TotalRevenue, week1_Revenue,...revenue} = foodRevenue,
    result = {
      Month,
      week1_Revenue,
      Month1_TotalRevenue: 
        Object
          .values({...revenue,week1_Revenue})
          .reduce((s,r) => s+=+r, +Month1_TotalRevenue)
          .toFixed(2)
    }

console.log(result)
```

I want to swap week1_revenue and month1_TotalRevenue order from the calculated object key. How would I do that. I recommend using these solutions.

Note: The original array was a string, so I JSON.parse() so the array foodRevenue is already an object

Comment: @52d6c6af That's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). `foodRevenue` and `result` are objects.

Comment: What I meant was that the original array that was parsed is not included. foodRevenue is the parsed object

Comment: `{Month, Month1_TotalRevenue, week1_Revenue,...revenue} = foodRevenue` is destructuring. Hop over to MDN and have a look at their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on that topic.

Comment: Clarification of what you want to achieve might help you get better answers.

Comment: The goal is to re-arrange the order of the result.My desire order is Month, week1_revenue, and Month1_TotalRevenue. The var foodRevenue is an object,so I am trying to use this solution to re-arrange the order.

Comment: Yes, and is there a way to void using Object... since the var foodRevenue is already an object (on my side)

Comment: How are you observing that the order is different to your desired result? The browser console? You probably know that objects are intrinsically unordered, although they do have a consistent order of enumeration.

Comment: google dev console. Yes, I know.

Comment: Did you already visit the link I've mentioned? It has all information you need to do what you want.